# Can move QT GUI thread as back ground thread and running a custom thread and wait loop as main thread

Tags: qt

Can run QT Main GUI thread a worked thread and make another custom thread as back ground thread?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. The GUI thread is always the main thread, by design.